# DATEDIFF does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, datediff

Here is my query

```
$sql= "select count(event_id) as cnd from wp_em_events where DATEDIFF (event_end_date, CURDATE()) > 0 and event_status= 1";

$result= mysql_query($sql);

$row= mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

return $row['cnd'];
```

This works fine in localhost, but not in server and returns this error 1305 - FUNCTION DATEDIFF does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Trying putting your DATEDIFF in brackets like this:

```
 $sql= "select count(event_id) as cnd from wp_em_events where 
        (DATEDIFF (event_end_date, CURDATE())) > 0 and event_status= 1";
```

I think there's also a bug in phpMyAdmin that means you have to put a LIMIT on the end in order to get it to work, so try this as well:

```
$sql= "select count(event_id) as cnd from wp_em_events where 
        (DATEDIFF (event_end_date, CURDATE())) > 0 and event_status= 1 LIMIT 0,10";
```